# Select only backfaces?

Tags: normals

Is there any way to select only backfaces in edit mode in blender? When editing models for mods/games I've noticed a lot of the time there are double vertices for faces, and because of this simply recalculating normals doesn't always fix backface issues. It would be much faster than enabling backface culling and selecting every face if there was some automatic way to do this, is there?

EDIT: Sorry guys, my question was not super clear. I would remove doubles from the model but the way the model is made there are some vertices that overlap so certain parts of the model are "loose parts." If I remove those vertices the model won't work properly with the animations.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm confused with your question as whether are you going to select back faces of a solid model (located on another side of the mesh) or faces with normals orienting inside and located in the same place as faces with normals orienting outside. From "*double vertices for faces*" part it seems to me you should try selecting all and W > Remove Doubles

Comment: Not sure to understand the question, but it could be about selecting faces having similar orientation (normal). To do that, select a face and use Shift+G then "normal" or "coplanar". Once done you can tune the selection in the operator panel (threshold)

Comment: You could select front faces and invert selection then. The Limit selection to Visible button in the header should be your friend here.

Comment: @Tiles Yes THANK YOU. This is exactly the solution I needed, I didn't realize such a button existed. If you post this response again as the answer, I will put it as the solution so you can get points.